# no "stdint.h" in arm-none-eabi-gcc(mac)

Tags: macos, gcc, arm, stm32

I'm working on a stm32f3 dev board, and met an error

```bash
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/arm-none-eabi-gcc/13.2.0/lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/13.2.0/include/stdint.h:9:16: fatal error: stdint.h: No such file or directory
    9 | # include_next <stdint.h>
      |                ^~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
```

In [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23973971/no-stdint-h-file-on-debian), I found that I need to install "arm-none-eabi-newlib", however, when I typed

```
brew search arm-none-eabi
```

I only get

```
arm-none-eabi-binutils ✔   arm-none-eabi-gcc ✔        arm-none-eabi-gdb ✔
```

there isn't a "newlib" package is available.

Besides, I can't find any useful information from google.

Comment: Beauty of Mac :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Do not install it with

```
brew install arm-none-eabi-xxx
```

Use

```
brew install --cask gcc-arm-embedded
```

to install the whole toolchain.

Uninstall the first installation before use the second one.

Comment: This worked for me when I encountered a similar issue when running qmk. Thank you!

Comment: Had this problem when compiling Iceman build of Proxmark3 on macOS 14; this fixed it! ‍♂️