# Failing to build embedded arm applications with brew installed arm-none-eabi-gcc compiler

Tags: c, gcc, arm, homebrew

Here is the application I am trying to build:

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
  printf("hello world\n");
  return 0;
}
```

Here is my output with the brew installed compiler:

```
> arm-none-eabi-gcc test.c
test.c:1:10: fatal error: string.h: No such file or directory
    1 | #include <string.h>
      |          ^~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
```

Here is my output with the compiler I downloaded from ARM. (These errors are expected (I'm trying to figure out why this is happening with the newer arm toolchain) - and when I compile a full embedded project this compiler works (albeit with similar warnings), and the homebrew installed one does not)

```
~
> /Applications/ArmGNUToolchain/13.2.Rel1/arm-none-eabi/bin/arm-none-eabi-gcc test.c
/Applications/ArmGNUToolchain/13.2.Rel1/arm-none-eabi/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/13.2.1/../../../../arm-none-eabi/bin/ld: /Applications/ArmGNUToolchain/13.2.Rel1/arm-none-eabi/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/13.2.1/../../../../arm-none-eabi/lib/libc.a(libc_a-exit.o): in function `exit':
exit.c:(.text.exit+0x28): undefined reference to `_exit'
/Applications/ArmGNUToolchain/13.2.Rel1/arm-none-eabi/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/13.2.1/../../../../arm-none-eabi/bin/ld: /Applications/ArmGNUToolchain/13.2.Rel1/arm-none-eabi/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/13.2.1/../../../../arm-none-eabi/lib/libc.a(libc_a-closer.o): in function `_close_r':
closer.c:(.text._close_r+0x18): undefined reference to `_close'
/Applications/ArmGNUToolchain/13.2.Rel1/arm-none-eabi/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/13.2.1/../../../../arm-none-eabi/bin/ld: /Applications/ArmGNUToolchain/13.2.Rel1/arm-none-eabi/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/13.2.1/../../../../arm-none-eabi/lib/libc.a(libc_a-fstatr.o): in function `_fstat_r':
fstatr.c:(.text._fstat_r+0x1c): undefined reference to `_fstat'
/Applications/ArmGNUToolchain/13.2.Rel1/arm-none-eabi/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/13.2.1/../../../../arm-none-eabi/bin/ld: /Applications/ArmGNUToolchain/13.2.Rel1/arm-none-eabi/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/13.2.1/../../../../arm-none-eabi/lib/libc.a(libc_a-isattyr.o): in function `_isatty_r':
isattyr.c:(.text._isatty_r+0x18): undefined reference to `_isatty'
/Applications/ArmGNUToolchain/13.2.Rel1/arm-none-eabi/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/13.2.1/../../../../arm-none-eabi/bin/ld: /Applications/ArmGNUToolchain/13.2.Rel1/arm-none-eabi/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/13.2.1/../../../../arm-none-eabi/lib/libc.a(libc_a-lseekr.o): in function `_lseek_r':
lseekr.c:(.text._lseek_r+0x24): undefined reference to `_lseek'
/Applications/ArmGNUToolchain/13.2.Rel1/arm-none-eabi/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/13.2.1/../../../../arm-none-eabi/bin/ld: /Applications/ArmGNUToolchain/13.2.Rel1/arm-none-eabi/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/13.2.1/../../../../arm-none-eabi/lib/libc.a(libc_a-readr.o): in function `_read_r':
readr.c:(.text._read_r+0x24): undefined reference to `_read'
/Applications/ArmGNUToolchain/13.2.Rel1/arm-none-eabi/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/13.2.1/../../../../arm-none-eabi/bin/ld: /Applications/ArmGNUToolchain/13.2.Rel1/arm-none-eabi/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/13.2.1/../../../../arm-none-eabi/lib/libc.a(libc_a-sbrkr.o): in function `_sbrk_r':
sbrkr.c:(.text._sbrk_r+0x18): undefined reference to `_sbrk'
/Applications/ArmGNUToolchain/13.2.Rel1/arm-none-eabi/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/13.2.1/../../../../arm-none-eabi/bin/ld: /Applications/ArmGNUToolchain/13.2.Rel1/arm-none-eabi/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/13.2.1/../../../../arm-none-eabi/lib/libc.a(libc_a-writer.o): in function `_write_r':
writer.c:(.text._write_r+0x24): undefined reference to `_write'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Why can't the homebrew installed compiler find the standard headers? I suspect the warnings generated and the headers not being found are somehow related, and that I don't understand what is going on with the standard library implementations in this toolchain.

Comment: you have a cross compiler, but what C library did you want to use with the compiler? and the C library then has header files, etc, yes?   newlib? glibc?  other?  what does brew offer with respect to the rest of a usable toolchain (binutils, gcc, c library...).   what is your target operating system, you need the toolchain configured for that target including a C library and matching header files?    that or just dont do operating system calls (direct or indirect, printf is by far the worst C library call to try to get working)

Comment: your compiler is complaining about not having C library calls to link with (and as mentioned C library calls are specific to the operating system on one end and mate with the compiler on the other end).  it does look like it is trying to link so you do have binutils. (not a header file thing....yet...it has made it past the header files)

Comment: @old_timer I believe the C library should be newlib, and that is installed by brew as a dependency. I just did `printf` as an example, I wasn't actually using that in my embedded project, but I was using snprintf. The target is a bare metal system, so there is no OS. 

But regardless, I think the brew installed compiler is not making it past the header files, so it is not a linking issue

Comment: the output in your question is from the linker.  the header file wont fix the link path.  and the header files are provided by the C library...which you didnt add to your command line.  so when you fix your command line things should start working.

Comment: but you also need a target, newlib is not a target it then needs you to fill in the files (for write and sbrk and such) for your target OS

Comment: are you doing bare metal (read: no printf) or some rtos or something like that if so which and how have you connected it to the toolchain?

Comment: the title implies that gcc gives you a whole toolchain, library and operating system...it doesnt...

Comment: @old_timer The first snippet is definitely not a linker error, which was the reason behind my question. It is bare-metal, no OS, I just used printf as an example of the stdio header not being found. 

I'm aware gcc doesn't give a whole toolchain, I was using the wrong brew formula to install the toolchain - and it only installed the compiler. That was my issue

Comment: Because the tools weren't responding as expected. That wasn't expected for reasons I clearly described, for instance the other toolchain being able to find the header. This is bare metal; there is no OS- that does not mean there can be no C library, and I was trying to use newlib. Regardless, you've been entirely unhelpful, and in the future I suggest when someone asks questions and there may be some gaps in their knowledge, you could help them learn rather than playing these games.

Comment: the tools you mentioned installing are not expected to find header files for a C library nor is binutils, if installed, expected to find the C library files much less the operating system backends.   The tool responded exactly as expected per your command line, for the tool you chose.

Comment: The tool behaved as expected.

Comment: The compiler was responding as expected. The toolchain was not. The brew installation of the toolchain did not install the headers in the correct location and that was the issue.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

[no "stdint.h" in arm-none-eabi-gcc(mac)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77249021/no-stdint-h-in-arm-none-eabi-gccmac)

I found this to solve my issue.

TLDR:

Uninstall `arm-none-eabi-gcc` from brew and install the toolchain with:

```
brew install --cask gcc-arm-embedded
```

Comment: your question mentioned string.h this talks about stdint.h.  string.h comes from the C library. stdint.h is tied to the compiler (not the library) gcc provides the compiler portion plus anything it wants to add.  string.h and stdint.h are two separate conversations.

Comment: the tool behaved as expected.  if you wanted stdint variable types with bare metal (no OS, so potentially C library) there are ways to do that just with GCC.

Comment: My issue was <string.h>. This fixed my issue, so that's all I needed.